# Using find and replace text in python

Tags: python, str-replace

I'm trying to modify certain lines present in a file. I'm searching for a text and replacing it. 
For example, in the following code, I'm replacing `vR33_ALAN` with `vR33_ALAN*c`.

Here's my code for a test case

```
lines = ['x  = vR32_ALEX - vR33_ALAN; \n',
 'y = vR33_ALAN; \n']

text_to_search = 'vR33_ALAN'
replacement_text = 'vR33_ALAN*c'
for line in lines:
    print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text), end='')
```

I could succeed in performing the above task. I want to add one more check before replacing the string that matches `text_to_search`.

I want to replace `text_to_search` with `replacement_text` only if a minus `-` is NOT present proceeding `text_to_search`.

Example,
The output that I obtain is

```
x  = vR32_ALEX - vR33_ALAN*c;
y = vR33_ALAN*c;
```

Desired Output:

```
x  = vR32_ALEX - vR33_ALAN;
y = vR33_ALAN*c;
```

I'm not sure how to achieve the above. Any suggestions?

Comment: this is a good case for using regular expressions.  I'm not an expert on them, but you should definitely google regular expressions and use the "re" module to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform that with and without the use of regular expressions. You can simply add the `'-'`character to `text_to_search`and use find to search for the new string

```
lines = ['x  = vR32_ALEX - vR33_ALAN; \n',
 'y = vR33_ALAN; \n']

text_to_search = 'vR33_ALAN'
replacement_text = 'vR33_ALAN*c'

for line in lines:
  if line.find('- '+text_to_search)!=-1:
    print(line)
  else:
    print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text),end='')
```

Or you can use the re module as suggested, for that you have to generate a pattern to search, as you're looking for `'-'`or add `text_to_search` as before. The `(.*)`is to specify that it doesn't matter the characters before and after the pattern.

```
import re 
lines = ['x  = vR32_ALEX - vR33_ALAN; \n',
 'y = vR33_ALAN; \n']

for line in lines:
  if re.match('(.*)'+' - '+'(.*)',line):
    print(line)
  else:
    print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text),end='')
```

The pattern `'(.*)'+' - '+text_to_search+'(.*)'`should also work. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub` with a negative lookbehind pattern:

```
import re
lines = ['x  = vR32_ALEX - vR33_ALAN; \n',
 'y = vR33_ALAN; \n']
for line in lines:
    print(re.sub(r'(?<!- )vR33_ALAN', 'vR33_ALAN*c', line), end='')
```

This outputs:

```
x  = vR32_ALEX - vR33_ALAN; 
y = vR33_ALAN*c;
```

Comment: When I remove the space after `-` i.e. `- vR33_ALAN;` the output obtained is `x  =  vR32_ALEX -vR33_ALAN*c ;`. The desired output is `x  = vR32_ALEX - vR33_ALAN; ` .  Therefore, I made a small change `re.sub(r'(?<!-)` and removed the space after `-`. I could obtain the output. But, how can we check for both cases? i.e irrespective of whether a space is present or not present after the minus sign , I want the output to be `x  = vR32_ALEX - vR33_ALAN; `

Comment: I tried using or `print(re.sub(r'(?<!-  |?<!-)vR33_ALAN', 'vR33_ALAN*c', line), end='')`.But didn't succeed.Any suggestions?